# Webstart application fails to start with -Xmx2G on Java 8u60

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a Java Webstart application that starts successfully with `-Xmx1G`, but fails to start with `-Xmx2G`.  Some of my users really need 2G of heap.

This seems to be a problem with Java 8u60 only, because I have a report of someone launching successfully with Java 8u51.

The failure looks like this: I see the blue 'Java...' splash screen, and then after a few seconds, *poof* it's gone, before displaying the Java console and without producing any trace information in the expected place.

The failure occurs only on those clients with less than 2G of memory available.  But, I am a little surprised that requesting a 'maximum' heap size could cause the application to fail so early and without any diagnostic information.  We are dealing with a 'maximum' value, after all, not an 'initial' value.  I read in multiple places that the JVM is not supposed to do this.

But I also remembered reading that the 'initial', if unspecified, is based on the maximum.  So, along with passing `-Xmx2G`, I tried passing `-Xms512M`, `-Xms256M`, and `-Xms128M`.  But, this attempt to shrink the initial heap size did not help.  I cannot get this thing to start with `-Xmx2G`!

Does anyone have any light to shed on this situation?  A solution?  A workaround?  In the short term, I'll change to `-Xmx1G`, but, as I said at the beginning, I have some users that really need `-Xmx2G`.  I'd like to avoid having two separate `*.jnlp` files, which would also entail having two separate `*.jar` files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is exactly what Webstart on Java8u60 does if the client machine does not have enough memory to satisfy `-Xmx`.  It attempts to start, and then *poof*, it disappears without any indication as to what went wrong.

So, I will end up having to build my application in different configurations if I want to enable the users with more memory to allocate that memory to my application.  This is because signing requires the *.jnlp file to into the *.jar file itself, and this *.jnlp file must be an exact match with the *.jnlp file used to launch the application.

Comment: If JNLP cant start, its unlikely a normal start works better.
BTW: did you check if 64bit jvm is used?

Comment: Funny you should say that---I seem to face a new webstart problem every 2-3 months, even though my app always starts locally.  No, I did not check whether the client machine/JRE was 32bit or 64bit.  However, I could make the app start or not start just by tinkering with the argument to `-Xmx`, and the failure point corresponded with available memory, so I am pretty convinced that is the cause.